# Represent a polynom on Z/2Z in hexa

Tags: c, hex, representation, polynomials

I am working on polynom over Z/2Z and we represent it by an integer in hexadecimal :
for example, 0xD4 is X^7+x^6+X^4+X^2 (0xD4 is 11010100 in binary)
And I just want to implement a function that prints the polynom just like I did with 0xD4.
So I can convert my hexadecimal number into binary and then print X^n when the nth bit equals 1... But I wonder if there is a simplest method to do this, your opinion ? (I work in C language)

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You seem to mix up the print representation of an integer (e.g in decimal or hexadecimal) and its internal representation. The internal representation is always binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything. Just test

```
if (poly & (1 << k)) {...}
```

to see if the `k`-th power is present (i.e. the corresponding coefficient is 1 rather than 0).

Wrap this in a loop and you're done.

(Here, `poly` is the `0xD4` from your example.)